# Dubai Airport changing terminals

Tags: air-travel, transit, transit-visas, connecting-flights, dxb

I have a connecting flight from Dubai.

Flight route:
US(Emirates) -> Dubai(FlyDubai) -> India.

For connecting flight at Dubai, I need to change terminals from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2.

Do I need a transit visa for Dubai, so that I can change terminals from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2.

(My nationality/citizenship is Indian)

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship? Are both legs booked under a single PNR (Passenger Number Record)?